# Query Errors from Microsoft Word Copy/Paste to PHP Form

Tags: php, character-encoding

Our databases accept ISO-8859-1, our forms are wrapped with `accept-charset=ISO-8859-1`, but when a user pastes from Word into one of our text fields, some characters are being lost. We get garbled characters such as `` depending on what they copied.

For example, a question-box is shown when pasting a bulleted list that uses the four-diamond bullet.

How can I ensure these characters do not show up in the field, or at least do not make it past our formatting functions?

Comment: probably more of a font issue than charset issue... just a thought...

Comment: @dbinns66 True, looking at the selected bullet point, it shows up as Wingdings. I'm not certain this is true for every instance of the query error we receive, however. Most characters are handled just fine, it is rare we get a query error for this, but every time it is from Word copy/paste garbage. I guess I should look into handling Wingdings copy/paste at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is its the dreaded fancy quotes that Word uses. Your charset does not support the 6- or 9-shaped quotes (what I call "fancy quotes").

If you can switch out your charset for UTF8, it should all work. Otherwise, you will need to sanitize the copy-pasted input and replace any characters that are not supported by your database charset.

Edit: I misread your post a bit, but I think its a similar issue to what I posted above. Since your forms are set to accept the ISO-8859-1 then I bet the text is garbled before it even gets to your form processing code. Maybe remove the `accept-charset` attribute of your forms to support the pasted symbols, then sanitize server side before you insert into the database.

Comment: Thankfully, we are handling fancy quotes. It sounds like we might not be handling anything copy and pasted from the Wingdings font. I will edit the original question to add this possibility.